# I need to code 2 time for detect pagingOptions attribute changes when using $scope.$watch()

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I can watch `pagingOptions.pageSize` and `pagingOptions.currentPage` when they be changed.

```
   //watch pagingOptions[pageSize]
   $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.pageSize !== oldVal.pageSize) {
        $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
   }, true);

   //watch pagingOptions[currentPage]
   $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
        $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
   }, true);
```

also I test by below way,it doesn't working. it doesn't work.

```
   $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage && newVal.pageSize !== oldVal.pageSize) {
        $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
   }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always code my watchers like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.pagingOptions;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // handle the changes here
}, true);
```

I think this will solve your problem, I personally encountered the same issues in the past and fixed them like this. Good luck!

Comment: $scope.$watch(function() {
  return $scope.pagingOptions;
 }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
 }, true);